# Is it possible to have a DLL without a DLLMain function?

Tags: dll

Is it possible to have a DLL without a DLLMain function?  What impact would that have, or does it render the DLL unusable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it is possible to have a DLL without a DLLMain. But it won't be same as a normal DLL.

As an example, Resource DLLs do not need to have code.

In Visual Studio you can have the /NOENTRY option so the linker doesn't complain about missing references.

From all specification point of view, the file is a complete DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can load a DLL library with resources only, for this purpose use LoadLibraryEx() with LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE.